# Run second query on page based on author of the first query

Tags: query-posts, wp-query

I have my single-property.php showing custom post type 'property', within this page I want to also show the custom post type 'agent' that belongs to the author of property, each author only has one post of custom post type 'agent'.

I imagine it needs to go something like this, single-property.php with the query to show custom post type 'property', get author from first query and run second query showing all posts of custom post type 'author' by the same author.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$post->post_author`,

so before your loop add `$agent = '';` then inside the loop add

`$agent = $post->post_author;`

and then create a second query after you loop ends:

```
$agent_query = NEW WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'agent', 'author' => $agent));
while ($agent_query->have_posts()){
 $agent_query->the_post();
 //do your agent loop here
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Won't reset do more harm than good here? You are not modifying globals, so reseting them after this will more likely break outer query, than cleanup after inner.

Comment: What about `$post` as far as i know it's being modified , and also if the query id ran after the main loop then it will reset to the main query,  could I be wrong?

Comment: For `$post` there is `wp_reset_postdata()` and I don't think it matter as much if queries are nested (if I understand question correctly) - it will be changed right away by next iteration of outer query. Anyway just a passing thought, it's up to Chuck to test this and make sure it works as he needs it to.

Comment: Nested? i assumed its a single post view so i wrote my answer like i did (saying on loop after another) not in a nested way, and i guess you are right about `reset_postdata()` and that it's all up to Chuck.

Comment: Yeah, likely I misunderstood about nesting, but I stick by reseting only as much as was modified. Approach makes most sense to me.

Comment: 100% agreed and updated my answer.

Comment: @Bainternet @Rarst   Thank's it's working as I had imagined, hopefully one of you can help me understand what wp_reset_postdata is and why it's needed that'd be great, I tested the page with and without it and didn't notice anything had changed, I've begun searching for an answer but nothing further than it's cleaning up, which I found here, http://www.rarst.net/script/wordpress-query-functions/, but what is it cleaning up, why does it need cleanup? Perhaps it's obvious by my questions but I am new to php & wordpress, having only done static sites in the past. Thanks again.

Comment: @Bainternet @Rarst I saw, wp_reset_postdata() restores (or at least tries to) global $post variable to original post, in the comments at Rarst's site, but still not sure why that needs to happen.. I guess I viewed the second query as an additive layer not something that was taking anything over?

Comment: @Chuck when `the_post()` method is used in second query it changes global `$post` variable to hold one of the posts from that query. So any function further down that relies on global `$post` and expects it to hold data of original post would fail.

Comment: @Rarst Thanks, so the reason I didn't notice any change is because this is the last thing on the page beside an endwhile and get_footer.